# PowerShell select and group by nested field

Tags: powershell

I have the following object structure:

- resources (Array)

  - resource (PSCustomObject)

    - Name (String)
    - Tags (PSCustomObject)

      - Owner (String)
    - more...

So I can do `$resources[0].Tags.Owner` and get string value.

The goal is to `select` just Name and Owner, and then `group` by Owner.

I can do `$resources | select {$_.Tags.Owner, $_.Name}`, but then I get a new array of PSCustomObject with two members "$*.Tags.Owner" and "$*.Name".
How do I do the group by the field named "$_.Tags.Owner"?

1. Can I rename "$_.Tags.Owner" to a friendlier name and the group by it?
2. Can I somehow tell `group` that I mean "$_.Tags.Owner" literally and not the object hierarchy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

```
#Demo Data Setup
Clear-Host
[PSCustomObject[]]$resources = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name='One';Tags=[PSCustomObject]@{Owner='Anne'}}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name='Two';Tags=[PSCustomObject]@{Owner='Bob'}}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name='Three';Tags=[PSCustomObject]@{Owner='Claire'}}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name='Four';Tags=[PSCustomObject]@{Owner='Anne'}}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name='Five';Tags=[PSCustomObject]@{Owner='Bob'}}
)

#Solution
# (thanks to zumalifeguard in the comments for pointing out this optimisation)
$resources | Group-Object -Property { $_.Tags.Owner }

#Original Solution
$resources | Select-Object Name, @{Name='Owner';Expression={$_.Tags.Owner}} | Group-Object -Property Owner

#Or a more verbose option which may be better in other scenarios
$resources | ForEach-Object {
    $Name = $_.Name
    $_.Tags | Select-Object Owner, @{Name='Name';Expression={$Name}} 
} | Group-Object -Property Owner
```

Explanation:

- `$resources` - pass the array of resources into the pipeline
- `Select-Object` - for each resource, return a collection of properties derived from that resource
- `Name` - take the name property
- `@{Name='Owner';Expression={$_.Tags.Owner}}` -create a new property called Owner, with a value as the current resource's tags' property's owner.
- `Group-Object` - group all of the properties in the pipeline together
- `-Property Owner` - in groups which share the same value for the Owner property.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried before to select with Name\Expression but I had a syntax mistake. Works now. Thanks

Comment: This: `$resources | Select-Object Name, @{Name='Owner';Expression={$_.Tags.Owner}} | Group-Object -Property Owner`

Can be reduced to:

`$resources | Group-Object -Property { $_.Tags.Owner }`

Comment: Good shout @zumalifeguard; answer updated.