# Powershell Attempting to Group object by a nested value

Tags: powershell

I have a json file i am converting to an object called $sets and i am trying to group those objects by a value that is nest in each object. each object looks like this

```
{
    "$type": "DeviceIos",
    "ActivationLockBypassCode": "example bypass code",
    "ActivationLockBypassStatus": "CodeValid",
    "AgentVersion": null,
    "Memory": {
      "$type": "Memory",
      "AvailableExternalStorage": null,
      "AvailableMemory": null,
      "AvailableSDCardStorage": null,
      "AvailableStorage": 24552280064,
      "TotalExternalStorage": null,
      "TotalMemory": null,
      "TotalSDCardStorage": null,
      "TotalStorage": 34359738368
    },
    "BatteryStatus": 58,
    "BuildVersion": "19C56",
    "CarrierSettingsVersion": null,
    "CellularCarrier": null,
    "CellularTechnology": "None",
    "CurrentMCC": null,
    "CurrentMNC": null,
    "DataRoamingEnabled": false,
    "DeviceTerms": null,
    "DeviceUserInfo": null,
    "MultiUserDeviceInfo": null,
    "ExchangeBlocked": false,
    "ExchangeAccessRequest": "None",
    "ExchangeStatus": "Accepted",
    "FirmwareVersion": null,
    "HardwareEncryptionCaps": 3,
    "HardwareEncryption": "Both",
    "ICCID": null,
    "IMEI_MEID_ESN": null,
    "InRoaming": false,
    "Ipv6": null,
    "IsActivationLockEnabled": false,
    "IsAgentCompatible": true,
    "IsAgentless": true,
    "IsDeviceLocatorServiceEnabled": false,
    "IsDoNotDisturbInEffect": false,
    "IsEncrypted": true,
    "IsEnrolled": true,
    "IsITunesStoreAccountActive": false,
    "IsMDMLostModeEnabled": false,
    "IsOSSecure": true,
    "IsPersonalHotspotEnabled": null,
    "IsSupervised": true,
    "ItunesIdHash": null,
    "LastCheckInTime": null,
    "LastAgentConnectTime": null,
    "LastAgentDisconnectTime": null,
    "LastLoggedOnUser": null,
    "ManagedAppleId": null,
    "LastStatusUpdate": "2022-04-13T14:07:11.417Z",
    "ManufacturerSerialNumber": "example serial number",
    "ModelNumber": "MVHW2LL",
    "ModemFirmwareVersion": null,
    "NetworkConnectionType": "Unknown",
    "PasscodeEnabled": true,
    "PasscodeStatus": "DataProtectionEnabled",
    "PersonalizedName": "examplename",
    "PhoneNumber": null,
    "ProductName": "iPod9,1",
    "SIMCarrierNetwork": null,
    "SubscriberMCC": null,
    "SubscriberMNC": null,
    "SubscriberNumber": null,
    "UserIdHash": null,
    "VoiceRoamingEnabled": false,
    "ManagementProfileUpdateTime": "2022-03-24T19:01:02.193Z",
    "ManagementProfileSigningCertificateExpiry": "2045-01-27T00:00:00Z",
    "MDMClientCertificateHash": "example hash",
    "AppleBusinessManagerUserId": 0,
    "ExchangeOnlineEmailAccess": [],
    "Kind": "Ios",
    "CompliancePolicyStatus": "Compliant",
    "ComplianceStatus": true,
    "ComplianceItems": [
      {
        "$type": "ComplianceItem",
        "ComplianceType": "IsSecured",
        "ComplianceValue": true
      },
      {
        "$type": "ComplianceItem",
        "ComplianceType": "IsDeviceAdmin",
        "ComplianceValue": null
      },
      {
        "$type": "ComplianceItem",
        "ComplianceType": "NotWiped",
        "ComplianceValue": true
      },
      {
        "$type": "ComplianceItem",
        "ComplianceType": "IsEnabled",
        "ComplianceValue": true
      },
      {
        "$type": "ComplianceItem",
        "ComplianceType": "IsEnrolled",
        "ComplianceValue": true
      }
    ],
    "DeviceId": "example device id",
    "DeviceName": "example device name",
    "EnrollmentType": "Device",
    "EnrollmentTime": "2022-03-24T19:01:02.107Z",
    "Family": "Apple",
    "HostName": null,
    "IsAgentOnline": false,
    "CustomAttributes": [
      {
        "$type": "DeviceCustomAttribute",
        "Name": "Account_Name",
        "Value": "example account name",
        "DataType": "Text"
      },
      {
        "$type": "DeviceCustomAttribute",
        "Name": "Account_Number",
        "Value": "0001",
        "DataType": "Text"
      },
      {
        "$type": "DeviceCustomAttribute",
        "Name": "example name",
        "Value": "True",
        "DataType": "Boolean"
      },
      {
        "$type": "DeviceCustomAttribute",
        "Name": "example wave",
        "Value": "example value",
        "DataType": "Enumerator"
      }
    ],
    "MACAddress": "example",
    "BluetoothMAC": "example",
    "WifiMAC": "example",
    "Manufacturer": "Apple",
    "Mode": "Active",
    "Model": "iPod",
    "OSVersion": "exmaple osversion",
    "Path": "example path",
    "Platform": "platformname",
    "ServerName": null
  }
```

there are many object similar to this one they vary with different values but i would like to group them by the value of account_number under customattributes as these are the unique accounts.
from what i understand from reading other posts you should be able to use a calculated property to do this but i cannot for the life of me figure how to do so.
i have tried

```
$sets | Select-Object Account_Number, @{Name = 'Account_Number'; Expression = { $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CustomAttributes | Where-Object { Name -eq "Account_Number" } | Select-Object -Property Value } } | Group-Object -Property Account_Number
```

when i try i get the message back

```
The property cannot be processed because the property "Account_Number" already exists.
```

i believe i have a fair grasp on grouping objects as i can do this fairly easy by any property at the first level IE i can do this easily by say BatteryStatus or BuildVersion but what i do not seem to grasp is how to select the right value from the object custom attributes.
the main thing i have been looking at the seems closest that i can find to what i want to do is this entry
[PowerShell select and group by nested field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031451/powershell-select-and-group-by-nested-field)
trying to glean my own answer from the answer provided by
[johnlbevan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361842/johnlbevan)

Comment: `Select-Object Account_Number, @{Name = 'Account_Number'` The word "Account_Number" is doubled here, thus Powershell complains. Call it differently in the calculated expression.

Comment: In addition to the accurate comment above, I find it hard to understand what your expected output is since there is only one appearance of `Account_Number`

Comment: to further explain my object structure is maybe 7k objects similar to the object above, varying in account number some the same some with other account numbers. i would like to group them by that account number, also i have change the name and tried re running and i never seem to get a response. and maybe i am going about this the wrong way.

Comment: a bit more clarification, the $sets object is reading a json file structured as such. <http://pastbin.com/hV1csu0w> i am using Get-Content -path $jsonpath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json where json path is my json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `CustomAttributes` nested object:

```
$type                 Name           Value                DataType
-----                 ----           -----                --------
DeviceCustomAttribute Account_Name   example account name Text
DeviceCustomAttribute Account_Number 0001                 Text
DeviceCustomAttribute example name   True                 Boolean
DeviceCustomAttribute example wave   example value        Enumerator
```

And breaking the problem in small pieces, you can get the **Value** of the **`Value`** property of the object where the `Name` property is equal to **`Account_Number`** with the following expression (using the Json posted in question as example):

```
$json.CustomAttributes.where{ $_.Name -eq 'Account_Number' }.Value # => 0001
```

In that sense, assuming you have an array of these objects as the one posted, you can group them using the same expression with `Group-Object`:

```
$json | Group-Object { $_.CustomAttributes.where{ $_.Name -eq 'Account_Number' }.Value }
```

As example, I have recreated 6 objects and modified some of these Values, the result is:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    4 0001                      {@{$type=DeviceIos; ActivationLockBypassCode=example....
    1 0002                      {@{$type=DeviceIos; ActivationLockBypassCode=example....
    1 0003                      {@{$type=DeviceIos; ActivationLockBypassCode=example....
```

Comment: and you sir are genius that is exactly what i needed

Comment: @ByronDooley good to know, happy to help :)